# How can I add an element in a flex column without affecting other item's position?

Tags: html, css, web, sass, frontend

I wan't to add a `p` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1navR.jpg).
I can add it, but when I use margin-top to put it down, it affects the elements above like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/523pC.jpg).
I don't know how to solve this.
Thank you.

HTML.

```
<main>
        <section class="home">
            <div class="presentation">
                <p class="hello">HELLO THERE</p>
                <p>I'm Lautaro Rojas</p>
                <p>Web developer</p>
                <p class="scroll">SCROLL DOWN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="presentation-buttons">
                <button>LATEST PROJECTS</button>
                <button>MORE ABOUT ME</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .home {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        .presentation {
            width: 70%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 5px;

            p {
                width: 50%;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: left;
                color: $WHITE;
                font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
                font-size: 70px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
            }

            p[class="hello"] {
                font-size: 30px;
                color: $PINK;
            }

            p[class="scroll"] {
                margin-top:180px;
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not clear about the problem you are trying to solve... you want to do _this_ but _this_ happens and elements are effected...

Comment: I'm trying to not affect the other elements when adding that margin.

Comment: adding the margin to <p>Hello There</p> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute;` is your friend...

```
<main>
        <section class="home">
            <div class="presentation">
                <p class="hello">HELLO THERE</p>
                <p>I'm Lautaro Rojas</p>
                <p>Web developer</p>
                <p class="scroll">SCROLL DOWN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="presentation-buttons">
                <button>LATEST PROJECTS</button>
                <button>MORE ABOUT ME</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

```
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .home {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        .presentation {
            width: 70%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 5px;
            position: relative;
            p {
                width: 50%;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: left;
                color: $WHITE;
                font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
                font-size: 70px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
            }

            p[class="hello"] {
                font-size: 30px;
                color: $PINK;
            }

            p[class="scroll"] {
                margin-top:180px;
                font-size: 10px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't <p> overwrite other elements if it has higher z-index?

Comment: Working fine, thank you!

Comment: @LautaroRojas No worries : )